# Date formating in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, format

I'm trying to format a column with date to 'Month Year' format without changing non-date values .

```
input_df = pd.DataFrame({'Period' :['2017-11-01 00:00:00', '2019-02-01 00:00:00', 'Mar 2020', 'Pre-Nov 2017', '2019-10-01 00:00:00' , 'Nov 17-Nov 18'] } )
```

input_df is

[image]

expected output is:

[image]

I tired with the below code which didn't work:

```
output_df['Period'] = input_df['Period'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m %Y') if isinstance(x, datetime.date) else x)
```

Pls help..

Comment: Make a function, try to parse it. If it fails, do nothing. If it works, then reformat based on your format convention. Return it all back as string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do with `error='coerce'` and `fillna`:

```
input_df['new_period'] = (pd.to_datetime(input_df['Period'], errors='coerce')
       .dt.strftime('%b %Y')
       .fillna(input_df['Period'])
    )
```

Output:

```
                Period     new_period
0  2017-11-01 00:00:00       Nov 2017
1  2019-02-01 00:00:00       Feb 2019
2             Mar 2020       Mar 2020
3         Pre-Nov 2017   Pre-Nov 2017
4  2019-10-01 00:00:00       Oct 2019
5        Nov 17-Nov 18  Nov 17-Nov 18
```

**Update**: Second, safer option:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(input_df['Period'], errors='coerce')

input_df['new_period'] = np.where(s.isna(), input_df['Period'], 
                                  s.dt.strftime('%b %Y'))
```

Comment: in the 'new_period' column , values like ['Pre-Nov 2017', 'Nov 17-Nov 18'] are changing to NaT.

Comment: Did you forget `fillna`? It doesn't show `NaT` in my output.

Comment: I tried with your code as it is. My pandas version is '0.23.0' . Would that be the cause?

Comment: @Tad see the updated code. This second option should work as expected.